# M2 - Check if product has custom options

Tags: magento2, custom-options, magento2.2.6

On the category page (in list.phtml) I need to check if a product has custom options. What is the best way to do that without abusing the objectmanager?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use

```
$isHasOptions = $product->getTypeInstance()->hasOptions($product);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Tuyen Nguyen!

Got it working:

```
<?php $ProductHasOptions = $_product->getTypeInstance()->hasOptions($_product); ?>

<?php if( $ProductHasOptions == 1 ) { ?>
    With options
<?php } else { ?>
    No options
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

For Magento 2.4 the following checks (in this order) if a product is configurable or if it has options

```
if ($_product->getTypeId() == \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable::TYPE_CODE 
|| $_product->getTypeInstance()->hasOptions($_product)== 1)
```